# How to copy SKU capacity for secondary database from primary database using ARM Template for Azure SQL failover groups?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template, failover

I have used the below link to create failover groups. However, using a higher SKU capacity on the second deployment scales only the primary database, and the secondary is not updated. So how do I update both?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.sql/sql-with-failover-group/azuredeploy.json#L79

Comment: Are you talking about Hyperscale service tier ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to scale your secondary database first and then the primary database.

As we can see from the official MS doc here: [Upgrading or downgrading primary database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview#upgrading-or-downgrading-primary-database)

> **The primary database in a failover group can't scale to a higher tier unless the secondary database is first scaled to the higher
> tier.** If you try to scale the primary database before the secondary
> database is scaled, you might receive the following error:

Error message: `The source database 'Primaryserver.DBName' cannot have higher edition than the target database 'Secondaryserver.DBName'. Upgrade the edition on the target before upgrading the source.`

And explained here as,

> You can upgrade or downgrade a primary database to a different compute
> size (within the same service tier, not between General Purpose and
> Business Critical) without disconnecting any secondary databases. When
> upgrading, we recommend that you upgrade the secondary database first,
> and then upgrade the primary. When downgrading, reverse the order:
> downgrade the primary first, and then downgrade the secondary. When
> you upgrade or downgrade the database to a different service tier,
> this recommendation is enforced.